# Is it wise to install mail and webhosting on one server?

Tags: networking, apache2, email, postfix, mail-server

I own a server, which runs apache to deliver webpages. Because I already own a domain and a server, I asked myself whether it's wise to install mail services on this server.

A mail server is very complex so I'm in fear it could lower the level of security. Furthermore, I took a look at [mailcow](https://mailcow.github.io/mailcow-dockerized-docs/install/), which should make the installation a lot more easier. But aren't there any complications with the webhosting (apache)?

What is the best-practice? Pay for an extra email-hosting service? Install email service on my own server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options:

## Host it on the same server

I would **AVOID** this as much as possible, for the following reasons:

- If you get a traffic spike your emails will not go through
- If your site gets DDOSed your emails will not go through
- If your site gets hacked then all your emails will be accessible, and the attackers can send spam, getting your server blacklisted

## Host it on another server

I tend to avoid this one, although it is valid, because there are a lot of free or cheap services that will do this for you, deal with all the config and patching, and give you secure remote access.

## Use an external provider

I tend to go for this one, as if your provider is large the odds of downtime are a lot less than if you host it yourself.